# Overlaying contour colorbar over pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following python code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')
Z = np.sin(X+Y)

plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
plt.colorbar()
plt.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=[0.5, 0.75], colors=['black','cyan'])

plt.show()
```

Which gives the following output:

[image: The wrong output -- no contour marks on the colorbar]

I would like to place the contour marks on the colorbar, like this:

[image: The more correct output -- contour marks on the colorbar]

I have experimented and read up but I can't see a way to effectively plot two quantities on the same colorbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.colorbar` returns a `colorbar` object, from which you can get the axis that it draws on with `.ax`. From there, things should be straightforward:

```
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
cb = plt.colorbar()
plt.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=[0.5, 0.75], colors=['black','cyan'])

ax = cb.ax
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ax.hlines([0.5, 0.75], xmin, xmax, colors=['black','cyan'], linewidth=5)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! Is there an easy way to adapt this to arbitrary contours - say if I had `plt.contour(X,Y,Z)` with no `levels` argument?

Comment: @Seabody `plt.contours` returns an object from which you can use `.levels` to get the levels.

Comment: `quadcontourmesh = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, colors=['black','cyan'])` and `ax.hlines(quadcontourmesh.levels, ...)`

Comment: yep just found that as soon as I asked the question. Many thanks both of you :-)